# Is there a time management tool that allows to study browsing time?

Tags: browser, screenshot, screen-capture, remote-connection, time-management

I would like to help my friend with time management, and I'm looking for a problem that can

- every X seconds (unless the computer was inactive for some minutes), measure what program (or if it's the browser: which website) is currently having the focus, and if this program/website is (not) in a certain list of approved (rejected) programs, store a screenshot.
- at regular intervals (or continuously or whatever is possible), compress and upload/send/... the statistics and screenshots to me (she's going to live abroad for months soon so she can't just show me regularly anymore)

She's rather neglectant and not quite tech-savvy, so requiring manual uploading/sending/... is not convenient (but possible if needed). There's no need for invisibility, this tracking is completely consensual.

What program would be most suitable for this use? After searching here I only found TimeSnapper, which doesn't allow in-browser distinguishing (which is quite crucial for her as she wastes most time on Facebook/Tumblr/... but needs the browser all the time for school work).

Comment: Try searching for "spyware".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into [rescuetime](https://www.rescuetime.com/). It sounds like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Toggl (http://toggl.com) has some interesting time-tracking functionality that may be in line with what you are looking for. However, for the compress and upload, I don't see that happening. Instead, you could just create a joint account on Toggl or look more into their group features (which I have not).

Comment: As far as I can see, it only offers a manual input of what you're doing. If this were a solution she could as well email me the overview, the problem is exactly that she doesn't realize where her time goes in and she doesn't have the discipline to rigorously insert everything manually, hence the need of at least automated tracking.

Comment: @user1111929 There's a lot more than just manual input/output as pretty good API for you to explore and use: http://support.toggl.com/api/